# Update row in gtk_tree_view

Tags: gtk3, gtktreeview

I try **only to update** periodically the value in the first row of a (single column) GtkTreeView but the RAM consumption keeps growing!

Simplified excerpt :

```
static GtkListStore* liststore;
...
gboolean first_row_updater_timeout(gpointer user_data G_GNUC_UNUSED) {

GtkTreeIter  iter;
gtk_tree_model_get_iter_first(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore), &iter);
gtk_list_store_set (liststore, &iter, 0, "some text", -1);

return TRUE
}
```

which is called in a `g_timeout_add(10, (GSourceFunc) first_row_updater_timeout, NULL);`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "g_timeout_add" calls the function "first_row_updater_timeou"t in a interval of 10 milliseconds until it returns FALSE.(https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add).your ram consumption is increasing because this "first_row_updater_timeout" function is going in a infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, just for the sake of simplicity. But why increasing? I expect  `gtk_list_store_set()` to free the old stored string and replace it with the new one (which here is the same, again for simplicity)

Comment: I observed that bad behavior on the macOS port.  On Linux seems to be OK.